# Usando Sessao em um controller MVC retorna erro

Tags: c#, mvc, session

Estou tentando usar sessão numa aplicação MVC, creio que esteja certo porem está retornando o erro:

> Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto

quando ele tenta passar o valor na sessão e o valor não esta nulo.

Creio que esse não seja o jeito apropriado de usar sessão em MVC, alguém sabe o que estou fazendo de errado?

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("FiltroSiltDet")]
        public HttpResponseMessage FiltroSiltDet(string DT_INCLUSAO)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpSessionState Session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
                Session["DT_INCLUSAO"] = "test";
                Session["DT_INCLUSAO"] = DT_INCLUSAO;
                List<AcompanhamentoSiltDetDTO> retorno = new List<AcompanhamentoSiltDetDTO>();

                using (AcompanhamentoSiltBLL oBLL = new AcompanhamentoSiltBLL())
                {

                    retorno = oBLL.AcompanhamentoSiltTransacaoDet(DT_INCLUSAO);
                }
                var resp = Request.CreateResponse<List<AcompanhamentoSiltDetDTO>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, retorno);
                return resp;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Da erro em qual linha?  Tenta adicionar a Session deste modo HttpContext.Current.Session["DT_INCLUSAO"]

Comment: Isso é MVC ou Web API?

Comment: tentei do jeito acima porem não funcionou também, esse controller ta dentro de uma API, estou com quase certeza q é por isso não funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nao é possível aceder ao contexto através de `HttpContext.Current` num `ApiController`.

Para aceder ao contexto use a seguinte forma:

```
var context = Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"] as HttpContext;
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884619/is-it-possible-to-access-httpcontext-current-session-from-web-api)

Nota: O nome da propriedade pode ter mudado, verifique outras propriedades em `Request.Properties`